# Text Expansion on Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland

Tags: automation, 17.10, wayland

Because [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), [Snippy](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coderofsalvation/46549e3788ade2f3a938/raw/875c069003f4194e110620bf248a3368725657cf/snippy.sh), and [Texpander](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander) all rely on the X11 windowing system (or indirectly on xdotool), they do not fully function on Artful's default Wayland session.

Is there  any alternative software that provides 1) simple text expansion that is 2) system-wide (browser, shell, editor, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Wayland is coming back as the default for Ubuntu 21.04, but I've long since switched to [Espanso](https://espanso.org/) as my text-expansion tool.